# Как это реализовать такой эффект в аккордионе?

Tags: html, jquery, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть аккордеон, но вот его края то ли осветлены, то ли еще что то.Как это реализовать? Спасибо.
Оригинал вот так выглядит: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону linear gradient. Вот тут есть кое-какая информация.

Comment: я это понимаю, просто вопрос в том как его здесь применить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пробуем так вот:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
 border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
        border-image:
      linear-gradient(to right, #fff, #333, #fff) 100% 1;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff, #F4FBFD, #fff);
}
```

```html
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: вроде у border-image с поддержкой градиента не очень хорошо?

Comment: Там просто тонны префиксов может понадобиться доя очень старых браузеров.